# Mongo Driver Validation

Tags: c++, mongodb, integration-testing

Is there a standard set of integration tests for Mongo drivers (Connection Library)?

I have a Mongo library in C++ that I want to validate (and if possible performance test). Is there a standard set of tests (preferable with data) that I can use to validate that the library is sending and receiving the correct data to Mongo?

> Is it a library or driver you are talking about?

"Driver Library"?
It provides the type to link to Mongo Server.
The types then provides methods to send/receive data etc.
And a few higher level concepts that I am experimenting with:
Handling all the on-wire protocol so that you don't need to.

You link against a library (So headers/library).

> If you are developing a new C++ driver I hope you have some good reasons to not use the officially provided and maintained driver from MongoDB.

No; I don't have a good reason (other than I want to try).

But I do have reasons:

- Experimenting with C++17 features that I have not used much.
- I have a library that automatically serializes C++ objects to BSON with no extra code.

  - This seems like a perfect test project to validate it against.
- I have a library that allows non-blocking use of streams that (with co-routines) allows me to write/read from multiple connections efficiently with a single thread.

  - This seems like a perfect test project to validate it against.

> the officially provided and maintained driver from MongoDB

Sure the official one is going to have a lot more support and probably be much higher quality than my one-man band version. But you make that statement as if people should only use the official version of a library.

I disagree with that premise entirely as it locks us into the same way of thinking with no ability to have radical shifts in how we interact with the data. I want to experiment and see if I can have a more efficient interaction with the data and maybe (just maybe this will lead to the official version saying hey that's a nice idea let us implement that in the official drivers).

Competition is a way to spur new ideas (though we are <strike>probably</strike> a long way from competing).

---

But to get to that point I need a way to show that my driver behaves at least to a certain standard. Which means that it would be nice to have some way of validating. Here are a thousand JSON objects stream those to mongo and validate you get "XX" behavior or result.

---

Answer (score 0):

The MongoDB C++ driver is developed open source and so are the tests to be found on GitHub:
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/tree/master/src/mongocxx/test

Your question could need some clarification:
Is it a library or driver you are talking about? If you are using the official MongoDB C++ Driver, why would you think it would send wrong results? Do you think your Library on top of the driver changes your values? Shouldn't be a test of the library independent of the driver be enough?
If you are developing a new C++ driver I hope you have some good reasons to not use the officially provided and maintained driver from MongoDB.

Comment: Unfortunately those are integration tests for the official driver not generic mongo integration tests to validate a drivers' behavior. But its a starting point if nothing else is availablee.